# GCP Hybrid load balancer not connecting to AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have a load balancer in GCP and an Instance in AWS and a VPN connectivity is there between the AWS and GCP vpc but the load balancer is unable to connect to the AWS instance and failing health check for that instance.

I tried creating a hybrid connectivity load balancer in GCP and gave AWS instance Private IP to it but it is unable to connect to the Instance.

Comment: Can you please add more details about your network configuration on the AWS side? (VPC, Subnets, Security Groups etc.)

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, why do you have a load balancer in GCP and the actual servers in AWS?